# Is there any solution to this?

Tags: utm

I have installed kioptrix lvl-1 in my mac os in UTM . But i'm unable to write any log in info . Can anyone help me?[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7Nh3.png)

I haven't tried anything cuz i didn't find any solution . If anyone can help me please help me !!

Comment: I don't think your question is [suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for SO as it is not, in my opinion, about programming of algorithms or software tools used by programmers.